# Possible to create instances on the AWS cloud which have access to Chrome Browser?

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Currently I'm looking to run my automation tests within the AWS cloud using technologies such as Selenium Webdriver, Java, Apache Maven etc.

I need to run my automated tests on specific instances which have access to Chrome browser. I can see that AWS offer a free tier, linux instances etc, has anyone had experience running Selenium tests within the AWS and also is it possible for a given instance to have access to Chrome Browser?

Comment: yes it is possible.

Comment: Login to AWS, set up a free-tier linux instance, and google each roadblock you hit...

Comment: or better yet... learn your tools and you won't have roadblocks.